# Can't open settings: gnome-control-center segfaults

Tags: gnome, system-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and as of today I can no longer start the "Settings" app. I've tried updating all packages and running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center` as recommended elsewhere, but `gnome-control-center` still segfaults:

```
> gnome-control-center

(gnome-control-center:111043): Clutter-CRITICAL **: 15:16:35.961: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to initialize the Clutter backend: no available drivers found.
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  gnome-control-center

> apt-cache policy gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center:
  Installed: 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.36.1-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

What's going on here? How did this happen?

Comment: Same boat. I have `1:3.38.3-0ubuntu1` though. On Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: did you finally get it working? same boat here

Comment: nope, at some point i just gave up and restarted

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating to Ubunut 21.10. What solved it for me was setting environment Variables for CLUTTER_BACKEND and GDK_BACKEND in my .profile (might be different if you use another shell, e.g. .bashrc or .zshprofile):

```
export CLUTTER_BACKEND=gdk GDK_BACKEND=wayland
```

After that, everything (e.g. gnome-control-center or evolution) worked again.